# Where can I ask questions that aren't Super User questions?

Tags: discussion, faq, questions, allowed-topics

### Thank you for your confidence in our abilities!

But have you read our [FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq)?

We get a lot of **non** computer related questions on here.

Yes, someone here might be able to help you, but you'll find that other forums more focused on your topic can give you a much better answer than a bunch of Super Users.  It's likely that your question will be down-voted and closed, often very, very fast.

What sites can people go to to ask the questions that are off topic here?

Comment: Maybe make the link to https://stackexchange.com/sites require fewer clicks and add [quick summaries](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/14934/slogan-motto-credo-goal-summary-of-site-next-to-logo) if needed.

Answer (score 27):

> **Please note**, [StackExchange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stackexchange) sites are marked with the little [image: StackExchange Logo]

### Computer Hardware and Software

Your question is off-topic if it's not about personal computer hardware or software issues, but rather deals with professional environments …

#### Managing and Administering computer systems in a professional capacity.

- [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com) [image: StackExchange Logo]

#### Information Security professionals protecting assets from threats and vulnerabilities

- [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/)  [image: StackExchange Logo]

#### Software Recommendations

- [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)  [image: StackExchange Logo]

… or is your question simply a shopping recommendation?

#### Computer Building & Hardware Recommendations

- [Root Access – Super User Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access) [image: StackExchange Logo](note: chat [requires 20 reputation to participate](https://superuser.com/privileges/chat))
- [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) [image: StackExchange Logo] (Beta)
- [Tom's Hardware Forums](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/)

---

### Phones and Tablets

Questions related to phones and tablet devices on Super User should always be about interfacing with your computer. If your question is about the usage of the phone or tablet device *itself*, there are alternatives:

#### Android Smartphones And Tablets

- [Android Enthusiasts](http://android.stackexchange.com) [image: StackExchange Logo]

#### Windows-based Smartphones

- [Windows Phone](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com) [image: StackExchange Logo]

#### Apple iOS Devices

- [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com) [image: StackExchange Logo]

---

### Websites or Website Administration

Questions about "the Internet" are generally off topic, unless it's about providing internet access or connectivity. If you seek advice for certain applications that only live on the web, or if you're a webmaster desperately searching help, see here:

#### Web Applications

- [Web Applications](http://webapps.stackexchange.com) [image: StackExchange Logo]

#### Specific Web Applications

- [Google Help](http://support.google.com/)
- [Google Communities Help](http://support.google.com/communities)
- [Facebook Help](http://www.facebook.com/help/)
- [Twitter Help Center](https://support.twitter.com/)
- [Wordpress Support](http://wordpress.org/support/)

#### Web Content Management Systems

- [Drupal Answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/) [image: StackExchange Logo]
- [Joomla](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/) [image: StackExchange Logo]
- [Wordpress Development](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) [image: StackExchange Logo]

#### Professional and enthusiast webmasters

- [Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com) [image: StackExchange Logo]

---

### Electronics Equipment

If your problem relates to electronics equipment that is **not** a consumer device, these sites may be helpful:

- [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) [image: StackExchange Logo]

---

### Graphic Design

If your question is about design, typography, graphics art, and digital media, but not about the technical aspects of your design software or file formats, you should visit:

- [Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) [image: StackExchange Logo]

---

### Software Development and Programming

Super User is about software, not about its creation. If you're doing some VBA or shell scripting, that's fine, but more complex programming issues are off topic.

- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) [image: StackExchange Logo]
- [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) [image: StackExchange Logo]

---

### Video games and consoles

Video games and consoles are off topic on Super User.

- [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/) [image: StackExchange Logo]

Comment: In theory, chat works well, as does actually doing research. geekhack and ocn for keyboards for example.

Comment: Related from Meta SE [Where should CMS questions go to?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19567/289691)

Answer (score 4):

Sathya's answer focuses on topicality.  Questions can also be on-topic but be a bad fit for Super User for other reasons.  Brainstorming questions often aren't a good fit because the question seeks to compile a list of ideas, and may not have an objectively right or best answer.  Similarly, troubleshooting questions can't be handled well in a Q&A format.

These kinds of questions can often be handled better in an open-ended discussion format as found on a forum.  Some forum recommendations:

**Windows**

- [WindowsForum](https://windowsforum.com/)
- Windows "N" Forums

  - [Windows 10 Forums](https://www.windows10forums.com/)
  - [Windows 8 Forums](https://www.win8forums.com/)
  - [Windows 7 Forums](https://www.w7forums.com/)

**Linux**

- [LinuxQuestions.org](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/)

**Product-Specific**

Most product developers have their own support web site, with a concentration of people very knowledgeable about their products.  This can generally be found by going to the product web site and looking for a support link.  A few umbrella organization support sites:

- [Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us)
- [Apple](https://support.apple.com/)
- [Mozilla](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions)

Answer (score -6):

The only visible answer (before this) lists only SE sites. Any question `closed` on SU as off topic is likely to be closed as off topic on any other SE site, otherwise would they not be transferred there? At any rate, all SE sites have a FAQ and I'd wager all of them state they don't allow shopping questions. So whats the use of redirecting "shoppers" to other SE sites?

Computer-related shopping:

- www.newegg.com (US based online store)
- tomshardware.com (publishes reviews and charts, not sure how interactive they are)

Comment: The other answer has a section titled *Computer Building & Hardware Recommendations* (in *Computer Hardware and Software*) with links to chat and the Tom's Hardware forums. So if you were redirected here after you asked a shopping recommendations, there are helpful links for that.

Comment: Nope. Questions that are off topic on one site can and are closed without reference where they might actually be on-topic.