# Which forums can we point people to when they're asking for shopping recommendations?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

Every once in a while, people ask for plain hardware shopping advice, which is off topic per [our FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq).

However, there are probably countless forums that deal with hardware, and possibly even encourage shopping recommendation questions.

As a courtesy to users who post a rather decent shopping question (which still is closed as *off topic*), is there any place on the internet we can point them to? Which sites do you know?

Or should we rather just leave them figure this out themselves?

Comment: rather old list, need cleaning up [Where can I ask questions that aren't Super User questions?](http://meta.superuser.com/q/855)

Comment: Yup that definitely looks like a mess. Maybe we should just combine everything that's still useful into one answer and get the info out of the question.

Answer (score -2):

There is a Forum in Beta called Software Recommendation. You should read the FAQ there before posting.

Comment: If you mean http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/, that is not a forum. It's a Q&A site from the very same company Super User comes from: Stack Exchange. Also, my question was about hardware shopping requests specifically, not software.

Comment: Sorry. I thought that any hardware come with software. Would there be any place where I would be able to ask for Instruction Sets for Chips like for the common Arduino cards or it would be off place ? I know that we can talk about registry programming in stack overflow. Thank you !

Comment: Not all hardware comes with software, at least not in the sense we assume. I was talking about "What graphics card should I buy for playing XYZ?" questions etc. I am not a programmer of embedded systems, so I cannot really give you any advice, sorry. Perhaps see if [electronics.SE] allows these.