# Where can I ask Linux kernel questions?

Tags: discussion

I asked [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/515299/where-is-max-process-size-specified) yesterday on superuser but got no answer so I figured I'd try the kernel mailing list next. Unfortunately, [the FAQ](http://www.tux.org/lkml/#s3-8) mentions that it's for development only and they don't appear to provide a list for users: "User space issues are not appropriate for this forum.". What are other good places to ask user space questions about the Linux kernel?

Comment: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/855/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-super-user-questions

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of any other places outside the Stack Exchange network, but your question would also be suited for [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

If you want it moved, flag it for moderator attention and we'll migrate it there – don't cross-post, please.

Comment: huh... doesn't seem like this process is a very smooth one. You get a limited quantity of flags. Presumably it takes time for the question to move as well, delaying the response. Will it appear as a new question over there, increasing the likelihood of getting an answer? Can I vote to delete in one place and re-post in the other site to speed things up?

Comment: @balor123 - Why don't you just delete the question then repost it on the proper site?

Comment: @balor123 It literally takes less than a second to move the question. I don't see the issue with that. Flags are handled within less than one hour, usually much faster. I also see you've just asked this question yesterday… answers don't always come in that fast, you might just want to wait.

Comment: maybe stackoverflow has spoiled me :) An interesting discussion but still doesn't answer my question of where else would be appropriate to look for this answer. Now that this question is a meta question, I'm unlikely to get an answer to it either. It is a meta question and it references a question on SU but it's not a SU meta question. If I pulled out the link to my original question and just asked for other places to ask questions, would it still be flagged as a meta question? Can I ask this on unix and linux or would it be a cross post?

Comment: @balor123 Asking for "places to ask questions" isn't a real question related to computer software or hardware and should belong on Meta. *> Now that this question is a meta question, I'm unlikely to get an answer to it either* – you're being a little pessimistic about getting answers at all, I guess? :) You can not ask *this* question here (about places to ask) on the U&L main site, I'm sure it'd be considered off topic as well and moved to their meta.

Comment: looks like I got an answer and a pretty good one at that :)