# Refer users to appropriate sites for off-topic questions on the On-Topic help page

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

On the [android.stackexchange.com on-topic page](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), they include a link to Stack Overflow for questions related to app development (since it is off-topic for android.SE but on-topic for Stack Overflow):

[image]

When I saw that, I thought to myself, "Well that's just dandy."

I see a lot of statements in new users' off-topic questions like "I don't know where this question belongs", "Not sure if this should be here or at foo.stackexchange".

For those blessed new users who read our on-topic page, I think it would be helpful for them to get pointed to the appropriate site for their question, if it happens to be off-topic.

For example:

---

### What topics can I ask about here?

Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about …

- computer hardware,
- computer software, or
- personal and home computer networking

and it is **not about** …

- programming and software development (please ask these Questions on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com))
- video games or consoles (please ask these questions on [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/))
- websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress (please ask these questions on [webapps.stackexchange.com](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/))
- electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except insofar as they interface with your computer (please ask Android-specific questions on [android.stackexchange.com](https://android.stackexchange.com/)),
- issues specific to corporate IT support and networks (consider asking these questions on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/)),
- asking for a shopping or product recommendation (no soup for you!)

Comment: related-ish http://meta.superuser.com/q/7395/235569

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting [What topics can I ask about here?](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic):

> If your question is not specifically on-topic for Super User, it may be on topic for [another Stack Exchange site](http://stackexchange.com/sites). For suggestions where to post your question instead, [please see here](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/855/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-super-user-questions). If your question is about Super User, you can ask on [Meta Super User](https://meta.superuser.com/).

The [linked MSU question](https://meta.superuser.com/a/4894/22317) is really a great reference, and includes sites and topics that don't have corresponding list entries (because people without an attention span to speak of weren't going to read a long list what's prohibited anyway).

It also and contains more than just a short reference: There's better information on what is and isn't on topic on the linked site (and where it's missing, it's trivial to add). Also, try fitting Apple SE, Windows Phone SE, and Android SE into that one list entry.

So, users should just…

[image: READ ALL THE THINGS]

… to get the relevant information on where to ask instead.