# Mention Software Recommendations SE on on-topic help page

Tags: feature-request, software-rec, help-pages

[What topics can I ask about here?](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) says:

> If you have a question about [computers] and it is not about […] asking for a product […] recommendation, […] then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

Since software-recommendation questions are on-topic on, well, [Software Recommendations SE](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) site, I suggest to mention it there to guide those having such questions to a suitable place.

Comment: Uh, It might help to flesh out the question a little better - rather than relying entirely on the links and context for readers to understand what you want to suggest

Comment: There's also [hardwarerecs.se] for, well, hardware recommendations, btw...

Comment: Note that there is a sentence: “For suggestions where to post your question instead, please see [here](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/855/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-super-user-questions)”. However, it’s disconnected from this part and generally easy to miss. I thus concur that this can be improved.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft I included fragment link

Comment: Have you asked on Software Recommendations Meta whether they would be OK with that?

Comment: @RobertLongson that? Why wouldn't they OK with that?

Comment: Because it may drive more low quality posts to their site. Anyway you don't know till you ask, do you? It's always polite to ask someone if you're planning to do something that may affect them.

Comment: @RobertLongson According to (this)[https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask] it may not. Did you see any low quality posts regarding suggestions? Also in this case, the site is fully dedicated to this particular category.

Answer (score 3):

As per the comments - alternative sites are already suggested on the help page

> If your question is not specifically on-topic for Super User, it may be on topic for another Stack Exchange site. For suggestions where to post your question instead, [please see here](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/855/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-super-user-questions). If your question is about Super User, you can ask on [Meta Super User](http://meta.superuser.com/).

I do wonder if "please see here" could be expanded to say "please refer to this  post on Meta Super User"

Comment: I don’t think think this would improve the situation much. Right now the help page is switching back and forth between topics: 1) target audience, 2) welcome topics, 3) topics to avoid, 4) search, 5) self-answers, 6) kinds of questions to avoid, 7) alternative places to ask, 8) Meta, 9) creating an alternative place to ask. Somebody who sees that their question is off-topic at Point 3 won’t continue reading unto Point 7, let alone 9. I am afraid that the entire structure needs to be overhauled.

Comment: An asterisk at the end of the point in the "not about" section and a bottom note would be better.