# Slogan/motto/credo/goal/summary of site next to logo

Tags: feature-request

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N7v0yvdkIHg) (“Uncovering Stack Overflow's TOXICITY” which is about SE being toxic to newbies) got me thinking.

I agree that the FAQ is too long and hard to find on most Stack Exchange sites, and it would help to put a quick Sprint-goal-like summary next to the title of, say, Super User, to indicate that Smart TV software questions are off-topic instead of blank space and random blog headlines like "The Overflow Blog
After the buzz fades: What our data tells us about emerging technology sentiment".

In short, a quick *"Personal computer questions only!"* would help avoid [off-topic questions](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/855/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-super-user-questions).

Comment: What's the video say? It might help to have a quick summary of what's relevant...

Comment: The FAQ is hardly too long when you consider that the only page you really need to care about to ask a question is the [on topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) page which is at the same sub-page on every site and is at most 60 seconds of skimming to see if your question fits the categories.

Comment: Plus this is likely a question for https://meta.stackexchange.com/. Unless you think that [su] is the only site with this problem.

Comment: @Mokubai I've considered that but didn't spot any misleading names in the list. Also ironic how y'all won't spend a few seconds on a link yourself instead of downvoting a simple request.

Comment: Copied to SE Meta. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/387485/slogan-motto-credo-goal-summary-of-site-next-to-logo

Comment: Questions should be self contained. Please bear in mind that downvotes in [meta-tag:feature-requests] means disagreement. Ref. https://superuser.com/help/whats-meta. Anyway, we well never know why people downvoted if they didn't leave a comment.

Comment: This feature request which is related to but offers a different solution than the linked question is about avoiding the ounce of validity that annoys so many as to generate dozens of downvotes and uncountable reputation damage.

Comment: @CeesTimmerman If you have a geniune interest in helping to build a community sense and make this community better please consider to spend more time preparing your [meta-tag:feature-request]s. In the more than 8 years that I have being frequently looking around SE sites, I haven't seen any post that just drop a link to a video and few lines of text that was well received.

Comment: Apparently the video was a bad choice and use it as the opening statement a worst choice. Have you reviewed previous features request here that were well received? How many of them start with a link to a video? Anyway, despite the video and the writing style I can't tell if the core of the request might be well received with the rationale provided.

Comment: Actually I doubt that the request will attract agreement votes as Super User is not limited to PCs (in the broad sense).

Comment: @Giacomo1968 With the requested and expanded summary, the simple background link gained more prominence. Shall I use a spoiler tag to hide it?

Comment: @CeesTimmerman It looks that you need to cool down. Comments are not intended for having extended discussions. Spend more time learning from previous posts. Start by [meta-tag:scope] and [tag:community-faq].

Comment: [MSE says](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301363/make-whats-on-topic-for-this-site-visible#comment1292587_387540) this feature request belongs here.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: I'm sorry but what you are proposing doesn't look to be helpful to solve / reduce the "problem" depicted in the video / about the FAQ being too long, etc. Actually, the concept is already applied in multiple places around the site.

---

I took the screenshot that you posted in Meta SE and added a red hand drawn circle

[image: Super User homepage manually modified with red hand drawn circle and arrow]

Besides the issues already mentioned in the comments, it looks that you missed that already there is a banner that is shown to anonymous users:

[image: Welcome banner for anonymous users with red hand drawn circle and arrow]

This banner has the text

> Super User is a question and answer site for computer enthusiasts and power users.

The above text is also in the site Tour, the article in `/help/on-topic` among other places.

Many of the questions that are not a good fit for this site  come from users that do just pay enough attention to post what they whant to post, they don't care about the site culture and workings at the time that they posted the question.

Some never come back, some never understand, some realize that Super User is not what they thought a others some way fix the question.

Anyway, this proposal at certain level is good enough to be discussed here, but so the current revision doesn't look to have the merits to get support from the community. You might want learn more about the culture and workings of this community.

## Related

- [Slogan/motto/credo/goal/summary of site next to logo](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/387485/289691)
- [Make "What's on topic for this site?" visible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301363/289691)
- [Where can we find a site charter/purpose that tells us the types of question on/off topic?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/387354/289691)

Comment: Nice banner, but i was already logged in, and smart TVs went from on- to offtopic.

Comment: Smart TVs are not personal computers ...

Comment: @CeesTimmerman Now you know that it exists and why you didn't see it. Good for you. The thing about smart TV's is irrelevant, you might create a new post about that. P.S. It looks that you need to spend more time learning how the platform that powers SU works as well about the workings of SU.

Comment: @CeesTimmerman How did you make this estimation? Do you have experience handling changes like this for sites like Super User? How many you have done and well did they go?

Comment: @Rubén I've altered the site's HTML for [this screenshot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/387540/177702), and before in [this userstyle](https://userstyles.org/styles/171536/se-no-whining). Super easy.

Comment: @CeesTimmerman Thanks. That make it very clear your understanding of the implications of your request.